# Do these metrics determine the same Topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $C([0,1])$ denote the set of all continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$.
Given elements $f,g ∈ C([0,1])$, define

$d_{\infty}(f,g) = \displaystyle{\text{sup}_{x\in [0,1]}}| f(x)−g(x)|$ and

$\displaystyle{d_1(f,g) = \int_0^1 | f(x)−g(x)|dx}.$

(a) Show that $d_{\infty}$ is a metric on $C([0,1])$.

(b) Show that $d_1$ is a metric on $C([0,1])$.

(c) Do $d_{\infty}$  and $d_1$ define the same topology on $C([0,1])$?

Part a and part b were fairly easy. For the last part, I know I have to contain one basis element of one metric inside two basis elements of the other metric. My question is, how do you contain a basis element of one metric in the other?

Comment: You're already assuming they do induce the same topology. What if they don't? One way to prove that might be to find a sequence that converges in one metric and doesn't converge in the other.

Comment: Oh so given a function f, we can show that a sequence in the d_inf metric that converges to does not converge to f in d_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For the last part, consider the sequence of functions $f_n$ that are zero everywhere except for a triangular bump going up to $1$ and then back down to zero between the endpoints $1/2^{n+1}$ and $1/2^{n}$. Is this sequence Cauchy in terms of your metric $d_1$, with a limit?. Is the sequence Cauchy according to $d_{\infty}$?

Comment: A sequence being Cauchy does not have to be preserved by a homeomorphism. Being *convergent* does. (Of course, this example works for that.)

Comment: @MikeMiller Good point, I'll add the fact that the Cauchy sequence has a limit (which fills the gap).

Comment: What does fn  converge to?

Comment: @YunusSyed The zero function, when you use $d_1$.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out a minute before your comment.